# Excel / VBA: Using a Function to Retrieve a Column Letter based on Column Title

Tags: vba, excel

Okay so I'm trying to write VBA code that will return a column letter which I can then use later on for selecting a column to work with:

```
For Each cell In Columns("AC")
```

but instead of "AC" I call my function to return a column letter based on the header.

Now my function to return the letter is working, it searches the first row for the desired heading (text), and returns the column letter if a match occurs

```
Public Function ColFind(colName As String)
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Rows("1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value = colName Then
            ColFind = Split(cell.Address, "$")(1)
        End If
    Next cell
End Function
```

So now when trying to use this function...

```
For Each cell In Columns(ColFind("Email Address"))
```

this method doesn't seem to work...

I've tried

```
For Each cell In Columns("ColFind("Email Address")")
```

However, this leads to an error. (I'm assuming it literally places the text inside the quotes instead of calling my function)

How can I use this function in a different sub in order to select the column with the appropriate header? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What determines the parent worksheet? Is there only one worksheet within one open workbook?

Comment: Thought this may have been the issue so I modified my code to specifically select the worksheet. The Sub im calling the function in does define the worksheet either way though! Still working at it as of now.

Comment: I'm not sure what you intend to do with your `For Each cell in Columns` loop, but note that you'd have to modify it slightly if you want to work with the individual cells in a column - i.e. `For Each cell in Columns("AC").Cells`. For example, with `For each cell in Columns("AC")`... `MsgBox cell.Address` returns `$AC:$AC` - not `$AC$1`, `$AC$2`, etc.

Comment: Why return the column letter? Just use the column number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you re-write to use Range.Find and return a variant in case header not found?

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim iCell As Range, result As Variant

    With ActiveSheet
        'Debug.Print ColFind("Email Address")
        result = ColFind("Email Address")
        If Not IsError(result) Then
            For Each iCell In Intersect(.Columns(result), .UsedRange)
                Debug.Print iCell.Address
            Next iCell
        Else
            MsgBox "Header not found"
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Public Function ColFind(colName As String) As Variant  
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(colName)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        ColFind = rng.Column
    Else
        ColFind = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    End If 
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The likely reason that

```
For Each cell In Columns(ColFind("Email Address"))
```

doesn't work is because Columns is expecting you to pass it a string. However, you haven't told VBA that that the ColFind function outputs a string. You can fix this by defining the function as:

```
Public Function ColFind(colName As String) as String
    ...
End Function
```

Comment: I've just tried this! unfortunately, it's producing the same result as earlier. I'll continue to look into this and post a reply if I figure it out!

Comment: What is the result it's producing? Is it throwing an error? If so, what error?

Comment: The data type being returned **IS** a string (technically `variant/string`) and works OK, as written, as an argument to the `Columns` function.  You can see this either by using a breakpoint, or, in the immediate window, `?typename(colfind("Email")) ` --> `String`. And, of course `?typename(columns(colfind("Email")))` --> `Range` as expected

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the help I finally got it working! Turns out my code does work but I was making a rookie mistake. I formatted the column header I was trying to select in Excel using alt-enter. I thought the header was "Customer Email" but it was in fact just "Customer" due to my mistake. I was telling the program to look for something that didn't exist. Thank you QHarr as well, your method did also work, and I learned that returning the column letter is just unnecessary work.